# collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cloudmade, route-me

```
Ld "build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Cloudmade Map.app/Cloudmade Map" normal i386
cd /Users/MPDEV/Documents/cloudmade2
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk -L/Users/MPDEV/Documents/cloudmade2/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/MPDEV/Documents/cloudmade2/libs/Proj4 -L/Users/MPDEV/Documents/cloudmade2/libs/CloudMade -L/Users/MPDEV/Documents/cloudmade2/libs/route-me -F/Users/MPDEV/Documents/cloudmade2/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist "/Users/MPDEV/Documents/cloudmade2/build/cloudmade2.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/cloudmade2.build/Objects-normal/i386/Cloudmade Map.LinkFileList" -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -lMapView -lProj4 -lCloudMadeApi -ObjC -all_load -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -lsqlite3 -framework QuartzCore -lstdc++.6 -o "/Users/MPDEV/Documents/cloudmade2/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Cloudmade Map.app/Cloudmade Map"
```

Undefined symbols:

```
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RMDBMapSource", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-RMDBMapSource in cloudmade2ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How do i solve this problem? I tried looking around but found no answer how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Your target does not include `RMDBMapSource.m` for compile sources, and probably more files. Check that your have included all files from route-me project to your target.

Comment: Sorry but how do i include files to the target? The RMDBMapSource file  is located in the route-me folder which is in the header/library search path.

Comment: @user755053 - Expand the target, drag and drop the files to the *Compile Sources* build step. Or select the folder in the project outline and checkmark the *Target Membership" checkbox column for each file.